# React - onClick event not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just started learning React.js and currently I'm working on simple "to do" app. I have encountered problem with onClick event on my submit button, it doesn't seem to work. I think I have got a problem with passing props to parent elements.

Here is my code:

```js
var Application = React.createClass ({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            title: "Your to do list",
            subTitle: "What do you have to do?",
            tasks: [],
        }
    },
    addTask: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("it works!");
    },
    removeTask: function() {
        var taskList = this.state.tasks;
        var currentTask = taskList.find(function(task) {
            return task.key == event.target.key;
        });
        currentTask.remove();
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("it works!");
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="app-container">
                <Header title={this.state.title} />
                <NewTaskForm subTitle={this.state.subTitle} onChange= {this.addTask} />
                <TaskContainer tasks={this.state.tasks} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});


function Header(props) {
    return (
        <div className="app-title">
            <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

function NewTaskForm(props) {
    return (
        <div className="new-task-area">
            <form>
                <label for="new-task">{props.subTitle}</label>
                <input type="text" id="new-task" placeholder="Type in task" />
                <button type="submit" onClick={function() {props.onChange;}}>Add task!</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

NewTaskForm.propTypes = {
    onChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};


function TaskContainer(props) { 
    return (
        <div className="new-task-container">
                {props.tasks.map(function(task) {
                    return (
                        <p key={task.key}>{task.text}</p>
                    );
                })}
        </div>
    );
}


ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>React to do app!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/react.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/babel-browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/app.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would really appreciate any help because I've been trying to solve this for some time now.

Comment: the `createClass` syntax is deprecated. switch to `class App extends React.component`. Also, I suspect you are mutating the state when you call `currentTask.remove()`? what exactly this method do? I think what you mean to do is `this.setState({ tasks: this.state.tasks.filter(task => task.key !== event.task.key) })`

Comment: @goldylucks I have been using `createClass` because I'm pretty new to React but I will definitely get into `class App extends React.component`. `currentTask.remove()` is just a draft that I have prepared and wanted to get it to work later on. I would like this method to remove tasks from the list so for starters I wanted to use `.find()` but the way you have pointed out seems better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't call the function:

```
<button type="submit" onClick={function() {props.onChange();}}>Add task!</button>
```

you can also write it like this:

```
<button type="submit" onClick={props.onChange}>Add task!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: I have one more question and I thought that perhaps you could help me. Do you know by any chance how can I pass event as onClick function argument up to the addTask method? I want to prevent submit with `event.preventDefault()`. I have tried passing it like this: `onClick={props.onChange(event)}` and `<NewTaskForm subTitle={this.state.subTitle} onChange= {this.addTask(event)} />` but I only get errors in console

Comment: try this: `onClick={ event => props.onChange(event) }`

Comment: It should work with my second example, it's equivalent to what @goldylucks suggested